# why is the auto ignition temperature of petrol is more than the diesel even though petrol is more volatile than diesel?

Tags: automotive-engineering

My question points that why the auto-ignition temperature of petrol is more than diesel even though petrol is more volatile and got least flash point than diesel.

Comment: This should really go to http://chemistry.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on Chemistry.SE

Answer (score 3):

I'd comment, but I don't have the rep, so I'll have to answer.

Because they're a measure two *different* properties.
Just because something is volatile (high vapor pressure) doesn't necessarily make it more flammable (low auto-ignition temperature).

You could think of volatility as more related to boiling point.
Auto-ignition temperature is related more to the minimum amount of energy required to begin a reaction.

Comment: Seems to me like a perfect answer. :)

Comment: So the vapour phase for diesel is more reactive than the vapour phase of petrol?

Comment: @Gwydionforge  the flash point of diesel is lower than for petrol aka gasoline.  Period.  Vaporization simply allows the entire load to oxidize simultaneously, maximizing energy release at peak compression.

Comment: But it still doesn't oxidize simultaneously. The gas ignites from the spark plug and the diesel ignites from random points or hot spots in the cylinder.

I have done flash point testing on jet fuel and diesel many times, the fuel flashes when there is sufficient vapour above the heating cup. The model in a cylinder is different, for diesel engines I assume the heat of compression causes enough of the fuel to vapourize and eventually ignite vaporizing and burning the rest.